# Bot framework + messenger + image exception

Tags: image, exception, botframework, facebook-messenger

I have a very simple bot made using ms bot framework and luis that's connected to Facebook messenger.
It works ok with text but when i send only an image with messenger i get "Sorry, my bot code is having an issue." I tried debugging but can't find the problem. When i send an image to the bot in the emulator i get "Exception: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stringToEscape
Anyone had a similar issue? How do you receive an image to your bot from messenger? 
"

I searched every resource i could find but didn't find anything that solved the issue for me.

Comment: You have an exception being thrown in your code. Enable all CLR exceptions in Visual Studio exception window (if you are using VS), that should help halting the flow and showing you the exception. Alternatively you can look at the output window in Visual Studio, it will log your exception call stack there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem: When you use LUIS you need to always pass an activity where the text property is not null if it is null it throws an exception, and that's what was happening in my case since when you send an image or w/e the activity text is null and those files are in activity.attachments. I hope this help someone who struggled with the same issue.